# Не запускается JavaFX программа в Linux Debian. Выдаёт ошибку:

Tags: java, linux, javafx, debian

```
апр. 20, 2022 11:03:03 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup

WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @456ce845'

Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw

Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)

    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:254)

    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:264)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)

    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)

    ... 1 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found

    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:276)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

На Windows запускается без проблем.

Comment: Возможно, это поможет вам https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в путях к библиотекам насколько я понял.. пересобрал проект в ide установленной в среде Linux и всё заработало.